# How to launch an activity when device is unlock with Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am just beginner to Android Development. I watch some tutorial from YouTube to begin. Now i want to add some feature to my app like in trueCaller app but in different scenario. Whenever my phone unlock i want counter will increment with one. [Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dizK7.gif).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add a receiver to detect screen unlock of the device.
The `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` Intent is broadcasted after the user unlocks:

Add the receiver in manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create a broadcast receiver which works to open app when phone is unlocked.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
        {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class); 
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);        
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }
    }
```